# Why is the "extract textures" button greyed out when importing a model from blender to unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

So I'm trying to import an fbx into blender, it has a lot of materials and textures, in blender all the textures are on the model. When I import into unity it imports without them on the model, i would use the "Extract textures" button but it's greyed out.

When I set the path mode in blender to "Copy" (which is what everyone says to do in order to fix it) it still remains greyed out.